# ExceptionInInitializerError while creating ant custom task

Tags: java, ant

I'm creating a custom task in ant, while creating that, I'm facing ExceptionInInitializer exception. 
I've placed jdom-2.0.2.jar in my ant lib directory so that the custom task gets compiled successfully.
Below is my custom task code

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Task;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;

public class Demo extends Task {
    private String init;
    @Override
    public void execute() throws BuildException {
        if(!init.isEmpty() && init!=null){
            display();
        }else{
            throw new BuildException("Please enter attribute init");
        }
    }
    public void setInit(String init){
        this.init=init;
    }
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("init value is "+init);
        try {
             SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new BuildException("JDOMException caught");
            } 
    }
}
```

This is my ant file

```
<project name="XMLUpdate" default="main" basedir=".">
   <target name="main" depends="compile,jar,runtask">
   </target>
   <target name="compile">
      <javac srcdir="." destdir="."/>    
   </target>
   <target name="jar">
     <jar destfile="./Demo.jar" basedir="." includes="*.class"/>
   </target>
   <target name="runtask">
         <taskdef name="dem" classname="Demo"/>
         <dem init="BOM.xml" />
   </target>
</project>
```

I'm facing ExceptionInInitializer exception
[image]

I presume that the error hit when compiler is parsing the line

```
SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
```

Honestly, so far I've not encountered this exception in java. what's wrong here ?

Comment: instead of catching Exception, in this instance for debugging purposes, change that to catch Throwable (Error's are not Exceptions and will thus fall through otherwise). This will at least give you better diagnostics for where to start looking.

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace, please. I guess, it can be obtained by tuning ant logging levels.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, and solved it according to [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jdom.general/4070)

Just use:

```
SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder(new XMLReaderSAX2Factory(false, "org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser"));
```

instead of the no-arg constructor.